# Python - Little beginner code confusion

Tags: python, debugging, python-3.x, error-handling

This is the program instructions I have to create:
The program is a Police Officer has to input a 'speed zone' for every shift they do. That speed zone HAS to be a integer in the answer they type in. Then they get a second question to fill out asking them 'what speed is the car travelling at?'. This input answer also has to be integer ONLY. If the speed the car is travelling at is faster than the 'speed zone' they imputed before at only once in their shift then 10 dollars is fined for every 1 Kilometre gone over the 'speed zone'. So if the car goes 10 Kilometres over, 100 dollars is fined. If the speed the car is travelling at is under the imputed 'speed zone' no ticket is fined. If any ticket is fined, the officer HAS to enter in the car model name. I.E Nissan, Audi, Ferrari... They all then have to be printed out designed to be like a police ticket. This all has to be repeated apart from the 'speed zone'.

Here is my code:

```
fine=int(0)

un_speed_limit = 0

while not un_speed_limit:

    speed_limit=int(input("What is your speed zone? "))
    try:
        un_speed_limit = int(speed_limit)
    except ValueError:
        print("That is not a number! ")
pass_car_speed=print("\nType '000' to kill program.\n\n")

while pass_car_speed !=000:

    try:
        pass_car_speed=int(input("What speed is the car going? "))
    except ValueError:
        print("Invalid number! ")
    else:
        if pass_car_speed==000:
            break
        if pass_car_speed > speed_limit:
            fine=(pass_car_speed-speed_limit)*10
    if pass_car_speed <= speed_limit:
        print("This car is under the limit. No ticket needed! \n")
    if pass_car_speed > speed_limit:
        name=str(input("What is the car model name? "))
        print("____________________________________________\n")
        print("   | P O L I C E   T I C K E T |   \n")
        print("   | Speed: ",pass_car_speed,"   \n")
        print("   | Fine Cost: ",fine,"    \n")
        print("   | Car Name: ",name,"  ")
        print("____________________________________________\n")
```

Code stopped:
The only common mistakes I have with this code and need help with is this message

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: (what ever I typed)
```

This only message comes up when I don't type a integer for 'what is your speed zone?'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were many errors in this code.

Here is corrected version, you should spend some time on analyzing this.

```
while True:
    try:
        speed_limit = int(input("What is your speed zone? "))
        break
    except ValueError:
        print("That is not a number! ")
        continue

while True:
    print("What speed is the car going?")
    try:
        pass_car_speed = int(input( "Enter speed, or 0 to quit: "))
    except ValueError:
        print("Invalid number! ")
        continue

    if not pass_car_speed: # 0 is False, non-zero True
        break # quit loop (and program)

    if pass_car_speed <= speed_limit:
        print("This car is under the limit. No ticket needed!")
    else:
        fine = (pass_car_speed - speed_limit) * 10
        name = input("What is the car model name? ")
        print("____________________________________________")
        print("   | P O L I C E   T I C K E T |   ")
        print("   | Speed: ",pass_car_speed,"   ")
        print("   | Fine Cost: ",fine,"    ")
        print("   | Car Name: ",name,"  ")
        print("____________________________________________")

print("Goodbye!")
```

Let me know, if you want some advice on what you should focus on in learning, to avoid them in future.

Comment: Thank you so much! You have no idea how much stress is taken off my shoulders. You should sleep easy with a smile on your face knowing you helped someone! Thank you once again! Much appreciated. I would love it if you could give me feedback of what I should do to focus on in learning and to avoid them in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to convert `speed_limit` to an int twice. One is surrounded by a Try / Except clause, one is not. Just remove the `int()` call from the redundant one that is not, i.e the line

```
speed_limit=int(input("What is your speed zone? "))
```

It also seems you assign `un_speed_limit` but never use it, you should probably remove it and just use `speed_limit`.

Answer (score 0):

I had to change the line

```
pass_car_speed=print("\nType '000' to kill program.\n\n")
```

to

```
pass_car_speed=input("\nType '000' to kill program.\n\n")
```

for the program to work.